# Asp.Net MVC Get value from Dropdownlist to PartialView

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

In my main page I have Dropdownlist of Cars. And it works fine.
And When I select one car from Dropdownlist I want to get back all car modells who belongs to the selected Car from Dropdownlist in the same view, let say under Dropdownlist. DropDownlist with Cars and Models of the selected cars in the same View (in Main view). I tried with PartialView but I'am not so good when it comes PartielView and html code 
This is my action to get `CarModels`, and I think this must be as PartialView

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetCarModel(int? carId)
{
    List<CarModelVW> listOfCarModel;

    using (Db db = new Db())
    {
        listOfCarModel = db.CarModel.ToArray()
                        .Where(x => carId == null || carId == 0 || x.carId == carId)
                        .Select(x => new CarModelVW(x))
                        .ToList();

    }
    return View(listOfCarModel);
}
```

In my Main View with DropDownlist

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="HasSidebar"> Car </label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CarId, Model.Cars, "---Select car---", new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CarId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

And here below Dropdownlist I want to get all carmodels of selected car
But I think I have to create `<div>  </div>` with Id or span .. but I'am not sure how to do here.

And here is javascript I'am trying to use

```
$("#CarId").change(function () {        
    var carId = $(this).val();
    if (carId) {
        window.location = "/an/GetCarModel?carId=" + carId;
    }
    return false; 
});
```

How do I get this action GetCarModel below Dropdownlist view? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think instead of navigating to the url you should send and AJAX request to your action which should return raw json data or partial view which you can display on your main view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like Roman said, instead of navigating to the url, you should send an ajax call to the control.

First of all, add an id to your dropdownlist.

Secondly, in the Onchange function add an ajax call to get cars:

```
var dropdownval = $("#//Id of dropdown").val();
var json = '{Id: ' + dropdownval + '}';

$.ajax({
    url:'@Url.Action("GetCarModel", "//The controller")',
    type:'POST',
    data: json,
    contentType:'Application/json',
    success:function(result){
        //Do whatever
    }
})
```

You can then do whatever with the result you pass back to the ajax call

Comment: thank you for response. In // Do what ever Place I just codes like this  $("#carmodels").html(result); but stil does not work. Do you Think something to do with action ?

Comment: @HelenTekie what is `$("#carmodels").html(result)`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to view results on the same page then you need to use Ajax.

add this div tag Main view where you want to display results:

```
<div id="carmodels"></div>
```

Change your jquery function as below:

```
$("#CarId").change(function () {
  var carId = $(this).val();
  if (carId) 
    {
        $.get("/an/GetCarModel?carId=" + carId, function(data){
        $("#carmodels").html(data);
        });
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for response, I did as you wrote but nothing happen. I even add View to Action GetCarModel, but stil do not show me the result.. I added alert(carId) and it popout car id but do not get carmodels in my view. I wonder if it is with my actionresult to do. Is maybe my actionResult GetCars wrong formulated?

Comment: I guess that rendered select tag doesn't have `id` attribute. So I would suggest to add: `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CarId, Model.Cars, "---Select car---", new { @class = "form-control", id = "CarId" })`